# Insert CheckBox.Checked status into database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I thought this would be simpler but its giving me trouble. I basically want a user to check a few boxes and then add each individual checkbox to a row in a table. I tried a CheckBoxList but decided to just add each Checkbox individually. Basically this is my code:

```
  Using cn2 As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
        If chkActions.Checked = True Then
            cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into [Turns] (Actions) VALUES ('1'", cn2)
            cn2.Open()
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
            cn2.Close()

        End If
    End Using
```

The Actions row is a bit datatype, so as far as I know its just a 1, 0 or NULL.  It gives me an "Incorrect Syntax near..." error. If anyone can spot the error or maybe a better way of doing this I would be truly grateful.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Didn't know!

Comment: You add only if checkbox is checked?

Comment: Yes. Someone will check this box and it needs to add to the database as true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're treating your `bit` value as a `string`.

Remove the `'` `'` around `1`. You also need a `)` after the `1` to close the parentheses

I.E

```
cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into [Turns] (Actions) VALUES (1)", cn2)
```

Comment: I forgot I need to add a non null code to the DB, so I adjusted the code to this.
`cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into [Turns2] (AcctNum), (Acciones) VALUES (@AcctNum, 1)", cn2)`
Its giving me a syntax error again.

Comment: It was the full syntax that was causing you issue. Wrong datatype and incorrect syntax.

Comment: Oh yeah I perfectly understood the change to (1), and I believe that worked perfectly. The only non-null column is the AcctNum one so I onl added the parameter for that one. The rest of the columns already have their information,  I just basically need to "update" a process with a checked box. As far as I know I don't need to supply data to the rest of the columns because they can be left empty/they were already supplied information.

Comment: I see you have removed the `'` in your new code :) if this answered your question please mark it as answered - or anybody elses for that matter. It helps us help you in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

missing bracket at the end

```
cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into [Turns] (Actions) VALUES ('1')", cn2)
```

Comment: This fixed one of the issues at least. I swear I tripled checked the code before asking. Semicolons, commas and parentheses are the end of me. Hah. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're missing a closing )

```
cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into [Turns] (Actions) VALUES ('1'", cn2)
```

should probably be

```
cmd2 = New SqlCommand("Insert into [Turns] (Actions) VALUES ('1')", cn2)
```